# How do I prevent certain form fields from showing up in the query string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a date range selector for a report page which uses jQueryUI's datepicker.  I have two fields for the start date and two fields for the end date:

```
  <%= form_tag stats_path, :method => 'get', :id => "date-range" do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :start_date %>
    <%= text_field_tag :start_date_display %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :end_date %>
    <%= text_field_tag :end_date_display %>
    <%= submit_tag "Run it!" %>
  <% end %>
```

Currently, as expected, all 4 fields are added to the query string as parameters, but I only want the hidden fields to be sent to the server. The text fields are just to display the dates in a user friendly format (e.g., May 5th) when the user selects a date.

Is there a way to exclude them?

I can't use `:disabled => true`, which would exclude them, because it makes the control unusable.

(I like having the date ranges in the query string so you can easily link to a report for a given range.)

Comment: To avoid having the fields submitted along with the form you need to have an empty value set for the name attribute. Can you not do something like :name => ""?

Comment: @StuR that worked! Can you post that as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved it using CoffeeScript:

```
  $('#date-range').submit ->
      $(this).find('input[id*="display"]').each ->
          $(this).remove()
```

But an even better solution posed by @StuR is to set an empty value for the `name` attribute:

```
  <%= form_tag stats_path, :method => 'get', :id => "date-range" do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :start_date %>
    <%= text_field_tag :start_date_display, '', :name => nil %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :end_date %>
    <%= text_field_tag :end_date_display, '', :name => nil %>
    <%= submit_tag "Run it!" %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: My problem with both solutions is that the values not only disappear from the URL query string (which I am also trying to achieve), but also from the input fields. Is there any way to keep the values in the input fields but *not* display them in the URL?